# Why is my Bootstrap column not staying on the right side with the same setup on some pages?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

On two pages I have the same setup with a column of 75% width and a right side column of 25% width.
On this page everything works fine (the column with the calendar is on the right side): https://maciunmacies.valoda.lv/izglitiba-diaspora/metodikas-skola-pupa

But, for example, on this page the column with the calendar suddenly jumps down below (it didn't happen before and I didn't change anything):
https://maciunmacies.valoda.lv/izglitiba-diaspora/talmaciba

So I have no clue. Maybe someone could help me understand why the pages are behaving this way?
Thank you!

Comment: col-lg-3 col-md-4 d-none d-sm-none d-md-block diaspora-banners is outside the row

Comment: Thank you everyone! Now the issue is SOLVED! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like on the second page you have mistakenly put the second column outside of the row class. see the two images [first page HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xRKc.png) and [second page HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9G8S.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have checked  your both pages.
It's div close tag issues.
**Solution :** you need to close row class div after col-lg-3 class div.
**Issues :** But now row class div it's close before col-lg-3 class div.

Answer (score 1):

"col-lg-3 col-md-4 d-none d-sm-none d-md-block diaspora-banners" is not inside the row.

Compare the structure of both pages

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).